# jQuery - how to detect if clipboard content has changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to detect, if clipboard content has changed? I want to detect if a part of the text that is copied and pasted originally comes from the focused/active paragraph element. The paragraph element is set to  contenteditable="true".

HTML

```
<p class="parent" contenteditable="true"> 

   Text that is first cut and then pasted 

</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that is not a clipboard. Second thing you can always compare the value to the initial value on a keyup event. Some of the code would be like this:

```
$('p').keyup(function () {
  $(this).text() // or $(this).html();
}
```

Now, either use the value as a variable and compare it to the initial value, but always remember, you cannot run `.val()` on a paragraph element. That won't do the job for you. You either need to get all the HTML elements or the text of the element.

To capture the paste/copy event. You can try this code:

```
$('p').bind('paste', function () {
  /* code here */
}
```

This would capture the paste event.

Comment: thx, but I might only be a word, which is cut pasted, then I cannot compare it anymore

Comment: @user1477955, have a look now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementByClassId("parentId").addEventListener("input", function() {
    alert("Content changed");
}, false);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ynegw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can. On input compare the text with the original text. If it comes from for example database, make an ajax compare. If it doesn't, create a hidden field with the original content and compare text() of .parent with value of the input[type=hidden]. If you want a snippet, just ask. But I think it is clear enough.